# The output of a certain part of my for loop

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int num, i, k, a[5];
int main() {
    a[0]=2;
    a[1]=11;
    a[2]=12;
    a[3]=16;
    a[4]=28;
    num=a[1+3]
    i=4;
    while(num>0){
        a[i]=num%4;
        num=num/3;
        printf("%d ",num);
        i--;
    }
    printf("8\n");
    for(k=0;k<5;k++){
        printf("%c ",65+a[k]);
    }
    printf("\n);
}
```

The output of this program is:

9 3 1 0 8

C B D B A

I understand completely how the output for the first line is but am rather confused about the 2nd part.

```
for(k=0;k<5;k++){
    printf("%c ",65+a[k]);
```

This bit here confused me as the loop the first time from my understanding  should go k=0 then print %c which comes from 65+a[k] which k is currently 0 so 65+a[0]. From the earlier part of the where its setting we see a[0]=2 and 65+2 is 67 which is the character "C". which is correct on the output but if I follow this same logic for the 2nd loop 65+a[k] where k=1 so 65+a[1] and a[1] is 11 and 65+11 is 76 that would equal the character "K" but that's wrong as it should be 
the character "B".

I feel that this line of code is where im missing something:

```
a[i]=num%4
```

but it doesn't actually set a number so still confused.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "*it doesn't actually set a number*" - why do you say that?

Comment: a[0]=2 sets the a[0] as 2 right, while the num%4 is setting the array number but doesnt set the answer to it I guess is my thinking

Comment: `a[i]=num%4` calculates the value of `num % 4` and then assigns it to `a[i]`, overwriting whatever was there before. Print out the array contents somewhere to see what values your `for` loop is operating on.

Comment: You seem to expect the values of the array to be what you assigned before the `while` loop. But in the `while` loop, you are changing the values of the array with `a[i]=num%4;` and contents of the array after the `while` loop are: `2 1 3 1 0` and hence, it prints the chars: `C B D B A`.

Comment: What does valgrind say about this code? It seems rather intentionally written to be obscure. Do you think that makes it more or less likely that you'll get any help?

Comment: main() always returns an int.  the OS and other programs can/will look at that returned value.  Therefore, you do not want to return some random value in some register.   Therefore, always end the main() function with a 'return( value );' statement.  Usually that value is 0, indicating the program ran successfully.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It shows 3 errors and 1 warning.   Please, when wanting help with a runtime problem,  Post code that cleanly compiles and still shows the problem.  then I/we will be willing to put our best effort into finding the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a[i]=num%4` does set the number. This is how:

In your loop:

```
 while(num>0){
    a[i]=num%4;
    num=num/3;
    printf("%d ",num);
    i--;
}
```

`num` varies as in the first line of output.

```
a[i]=num%4;
```

actually sets the values in the array as follows:

Initially, `i=4` and `num=28`. Therefore,

`a[i]=num%4;`  sets `a[4]` as `28%4=0`. Therefore, your last character is `A+0=A`.

Then `i=3`, and `num=9`. Therefore,

`a[i]=num%4;`  sets `a[3]` as `9%4=1`. Therefore, your second last character is `A+1=B`.

Then `i=2`, and `num=3`. Therefore,

`a[i]=num%4;`  sets `a[2]` as `3%4=3`. Therefore, your third last character is `A+3=D`.

Then `i=1`, and `num=1`. Therefore,

`a[i]=num%4;`  sets `a[1]` as `1%4=1`. Therefore, your fourth last character is `A+1=B`.

Then `i=0`, and `num=0`. Therefore,

We do not enter the loop. `a[0]=C`, its initial value.

Hence we get: `C B D B A`